# Is it possible to recover unsaved data in Illustrator cs4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, file-format, cs4

I was working on a file and Illustrator suddenly crashed, just wondered if the data gets saved somewhere.

Any tips?

Comment: No. Sorry. It's gone.

Answer (score 2):

No. Illustrator does not have the same facility which Adobe InDesign has where work in progress is saved periodically to a temp directory.